# Unable to run time triggered function with CosmosDB Binding in Azure as SpringBoot App

Tags: azure, spring-boot, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

Unable to Package the dummy app

```
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource to D:\MyFiles\akarforma\Downloads\hello-spring-function-azure-master\target\azure-functions\spring-mongtotimer
[INFO] Copied successfully.
[INFO] Step 7 of 7: Installing function extensions if needed
Extensions command requires dotnet on your path. Please make sure to install dotnet (.NET Core SDK) for your system from https://www.microsoft.com/net/download
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Failed to install the Function extensions
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------
```

And after publishing it into the Azure getting

Error:

```
Function (spring-mongtotimer/hellodummy) Error: The binding type(s) 'cosmosDB' are not registered. Please ensure the type is correct and the binding extension is installed.





   @FunctionName("helloTimer") 
public void execute(@TimerTrigger(name = "timerInfo", schedule = "*/1 * * * * *") String timerInfo,@CosmosDBInput(name = "documents", databaseName = "db1", collectionName = "col1", connectionStringSetting = "dbStr") Optional<String>documents,ExecutionContext context){
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like in order to generate the package, you need the `dotnet` CLI. The error you are getting is because the package you generate does not contain the Extension (Cosmos DB is an extension):

```
Extensions command requires dotnet on your path. Please make sure to install dotnet (.NET Core SDK) for your system from https://www.microsoft.com/net/download
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Failed to install the Function extensions
```

Are you using the latest Azure Functions CLI?

Comment: what you say makes sense....i tried this npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@core --unsafe-perm true and it started to create a package.....thr must be somwthing wrong with the version.

Comment: But still when I try to run it on my local system I get "The binding type(s) 'cosmosDB' are not registered. Please ensure the type is correct and the binding extension is installed."

Comment: That error means that the Extension that references 'cosmosDB' is not loaded. Underneath it is actually a C# Extension, but I'm not familiar with Java enough to know why it is not loading though.